# How do you only build a file's project using Visual Studio's Command Window?

Tags: visual-studio, build, projects-and-solutions, command

Ctrl-Shift-B, by default, builds an entire solution. An entire solution may contain many projects. Compiling all at the same time may be very slow, especially when development is only occurring on a single project.

I have tried t remap Ctrl-Shift-B to Build.BuildOnlyProject, but it does not work. Nothing happens.

From the menu, the following option does exactly what I want:

```
Build -> Build [MY PROJECT NAME]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is **Build.BuildSelection**

To bind that to a key, click **Tools | Customize | Keyboard...** then search for it to bind it.

**Note**: Build.BuildOnlyProject does not work all the way through VS2010, at least.